# Creating a csv file from an html that does not have a table element to use with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, excel, csv, beautifulsoup

Thank you in advance for any help. I have a current CSV of historical data relating to the CFTC url: https://www.cftc.gov/dea/options/other_lof.htm

I am looking to create a script to pull the data from this site once a week and update my historical data CSV automatically. I am currently stuck when trying to import only the "Random Length Lumber" data into a new CSV. The HTML code looks like this:

```
        <pre> <!--ih:includeHTML file="other_lof.txt"-->PALLADIUM - NEW YORK MERCANTILE EXCHANGE... # It then continues listing ALL data from all of the commodities 


<!--/ih:includeHTML-->
    </pre>
```

and continues listing all the data for all of the commodities.

My python code starts like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request


page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
# table = soup.find('')
```

From here I would like to only access the Lumber data and export to excel, however until I can select the data I want, I do not want to write all of the data over to excel. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

URL that you provided is not in CSV format, its plain ascii formatted table report.

cftc.gov provides combined "Disaggregated Futures and Options Commitments" report in plain CSV format for all commodities here:

https://www.cftc.gov/dea/newcot/c_disagg.txt

and here you can find field names for this kind of report:

https://www.cftc.gov/MarketReports/CommitmentsofTraders/HistoricalViewable/CFTC_023168

Here is a sample Python code to parse those details:

```
import requests, csv, lxml.etree, io


def get_dissag():
    output = []

    feed_url = 'https://www.cftc.gov/dea/newcot/c_disagg.txt'
    fields_url = 'https://www.cftc.gov/MarketReports/CommitmentsofTraders/HistoricalViewable/CFTC_023168'

    fields_response = requests.get(fields_url)
    doc = lxml.etree.HTML(fields_response.content.decode())
    header = [field.split(' ')[1] for field in doc.xpath("//td/p/text()")]

    response = requests.get(feed_url)
    f = io.StringIO(response.content.decode())
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in csv_reader:
        row_dict = {}
        for index, value in enumerate(row):
            row_dict[header[index]] = value.strip()
        output.append(row_dict)

    return output


print(get_dissag())
```

Answer (score -2):

After fetching the HTML page source code try to extract all the list tag items from the source as in general, the table of contents is prepared using 'li' tag in HTML. Study the Source code and find out the class of the list tag which is used to give a unique identity to the element

```
tr = soup.findChildren('li',class_= "toclevel-1")
for item in tr:
    print(item.text)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!